# How to pass parameters between lua endpoints in Openresty

Tags: lua, openresty

I am trying to expose two Openresty endpoints

- first should receive a call from Python backend about generated ID and some time info
- second should get parameters from the first endpoint and use it for processing

I have the following location block

```
location /cookie {
        content_by_lua_file '/opt/lreqproc/arguments.lua';
}

location /check {
        content_by_lua_file '/opt/lreqproc/check.lua';
}
```

In my arguments.lua I have the following

```
cid, ttl = nil, nil

local function setCookieID()
    -- read the arguments from the request
    local arg1 = ngx.var.arg_arg1
    local arg2 = ngx.var.arg_arg2

    -- compute the response
    local response = "Hello, " .. arg1 .. " " .. arg2 .. "!"

    -- set the response headers
    ngx.header["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
    ngx.header["Content-Length"] = string.len(response)
    ngx.header["X-Args"] = "arg1=" .. arg1 .. "&arg2=" .. arg2

    cid, ttl = arg1, arg2
    -- write the response to the HTTP response body
    ngx.print(response)
end

local function getCookieID()
    return cid, ttl
end

local setValues = setCookieID()

return {
    getCookieID = getCookieID
}
```

Whenever I am sending call, the answer is correct

```
curl -I -X GET "http://localhost/cookie?arg1=foo&arg2=bar"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty
Date: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 08:28:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
X-Args: arg1=foo&arg2=bar
```

However I am not able to constuct the check.lua script to view params from the first function

```
local args = require "arguments"
local cookieID = args.getCookieID()
```

This gives me something like that in logs

```
*168 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /opt/lreqproc/check.lua:2: attempt to index local 'args' (a number value)#012stack traceback:#012coroutine 0:#012#011/opt/lreqproc/check.lua: in main chunk, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /check HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```